# How to use properties (element locators) from another class

Tags: selenium, java, page-objects

[image]

As on the image I have few elements on the `POMLogin.java` class (which i think I am following POM).
And I need to access these elements from another class which is `jUnitLogintest.java`

1. How am i going to access the elements from other class?
2. Am i following correct approach of POM?

Comment: Voting to leave this question open, it is very specific. My Summary: "How can I reach properties of another class, and how would I do this according to the pageObject pattern/model?"

Comment: If you need to access locators from another PageObject, you are doing it WRONG. You need to level up you OOP skills.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the class Static: http://www.javatpoint.com/static-keyword-in-java

And then add a getter method `getUsername()` to return the `By`.

Then you could use it like:

```
By username = POMLogin.getUsername();
```

No, it is not following the POM correctly. You should always instantiate the class with new. Also I think PageObjects should return page objects. Your login page would return the page after login. Also the tests or other PageObject should not know the internal elements of another page. You should use the actions to interact with the page. An example loginTest:

```
// Arrange
User admin = new User("admin");
Page loginPage = new POMLogin();
Page pageAfterLogin = loginPage.authenticate(admin.username, admin.password);

// Act
Boolean result = pageAfterLogin.checkLogoutButtonIsVisible();

// Assert
Assert.True(result)
```

Java is not my main language there could be better ways (an errors in my example code), maybe ask on StackOverflow, this question is a bit off-topic here as it is a programming question, not a testing.

Also read this about getting variables from a class without a getter: https://dzone.com/articles/java-properties-without

Comment: Yes you are correct, I make the variable static and it works.

Comment: @ChathuD it works, but keep in mind it might not be the cleanest way to code it. You create a hardcoded dependencies between the two classes. If in doubt spar with your local Java developers.

Comment: Roger that niels